# Are tin-skinned and teen-skinned correct words?

Tags: grammaticality

I will upload a photo as a primary to my Facebook profile on my birthday. Then, I am writing a good caption for it. Are tin-skinned (metal skin) and teen-skinned (teenager skin) correct words? Here will be the caption of the photo:

> Photo Caption might be thin-skinned cheek, thin-skinned chick, thin-skinned chick, teen-skinned cheek, teen-skinned chick, teen-skinned chick, tin-skinned cheek, tin-skinned chick or tin-skinned chick. If thin-skinned cheek then the skin is not thick but thinnish else if thin-skinned chick then it might whether have a feather or flock together with another else if thin-skinned chick then the chick is not thick-skinned but either touchy or tetchy such a girly else if teen-skinned cheek, teen-skinned chick and teen-skinned chick then their age might be between thirteen and ninteen else if tin-skinned cheek then simply tinned cheek not tinned can else if tin-skinned chick then feather is not needed during bad weather else the chick might be an android. #wordplay

I am a programmer and loves to play words.

Comment: Why not use a dictionary?

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I checked the skinned word in Merriam-Webster Dictionary on my Android but I'm not sure if tin-skinned and teen-skinned are correct or might contain other bad meaning. Are those word correct?

Comment: Don't forget _ten-skinned_ and _thin-skeined_.

Comment: *tan-skinned*? If so, just *tanned*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In language there is often no 'correct' answer, just what sounds right to the majority of fluent users.

I would say that tin-skinned is an acceptable though unusual construction because tin is a substance and is analogous to stone-clad, brick-built, copper-plated, all three of which are in common use.

Teen is not a substance but here being used as an adjective. You might think that it works similarly to pale-skinned or thick-skinned (both again commonly heard and sounding 'right'). But it sounds strange to the ear and would most likely either be attributed to unfamiliarity with the language OR, in the case of someone clearly exceptionally skilled in the language, a deliberate attempt to surprise the reader with a novel concept, as a poetical or literary device. So to that extent it's not wrong as in forbidden by the grammar, but it sounds strange, unusual.

If Milton, Byron or Shakespeare, maybe James Joyce, had used 'teen-skinned', nobody would be shocked on linguistic grounds. If a learner used it, people would probably think 'mistake'.

Inexplicably, 'fresh-skinned' sounds fine to my ear.

Since your example is obviously one where there is a delight in playing with words and creating interesting contrasts of ideas, teen-skinned fits in perfectly well on the grounds of literary exploration.